# bash Заменить все одинаковые файлы символическими ссылками

Tags: bash, symlinks

В каталоге сервера лежат файлы, загруженные на сайт пользователями.
Нередко пользователи по ошибке загружают один и тот же файл много раз.
Имена у этих файлов получаются, например, такие: ustav.pdf, ustav_0.pdf, ustav_1.pdf
Разбираться какой из этих файлов настоящий - времени нет.

Хотелось бы пройтись скриптом, чтобы все подобные файлы, если они одинаковой длины, заменились на символическую ссылку на один из них.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как такой скрипт написать?

Comment: можно выполнить где то такую команду  `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum - | sort`. Файлы, у которых одинаковые md5 суммы, скорее всего одинаковые. Сами md5 суммы можно сохранить в файл, пройтись но ним uniq, найти дубликаты, а потом уже что то думать. Может там 3-4 файла дубликатов.

Comment: Ссылки рекомендую делать все таки жесткие, а не символические. Потому как иначе будут сложности с удалением файлов. Заходите файл удалить, а на него симлинки были и эти симлинки станут в никуда. С жесткими ссылками такого не произойдет. А вообще лучше бы логику проверки одинаковых файлов заложить в скрипт обеспечивающий закачку файла пользователем, чем постфактум постоянно перерывать всю папку на дубли

Answer (score 3):

заменять лучше не [символическими ссылками (*symlinks*)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0), а [«жёсткими» (*hardlinks*)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D1%91%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0).

сделать это можно, например, с помощью скрипта *findup*, входящего в пакет [*fslint*](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=fslint&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all):

```
$ /usr/share/fslint/fslint/findup -m каталог ...
```

---

кстати, в этом пакете есть и gui-обёртка *fslint-gui*.

Comment: А если не findup? Хостинг не дает ставить пакеты...

Comment: *А если не findup?* — а почему нет? пакет представляет собой набор скриптов (там очень много всяких разных функций реализовано). скачайте, распакуйте, и используйте. или свой небольшой скрипт напишите, опираясь на реализацию из этого пакета.